# How to get a file from jar?

Tags: java, jar

I need a file `filename.txt` which is inside a jar file. How can I read the contents of the txt file using code? Are there any libraries available for working with *.jar files?

Comment: Do you want to get it programmatically, or just extract it? If the former, is the yyy.jar in the classpath or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream stream = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(stream);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(s.next());
        }
    }
}
```

The jar needs to be on the classpath of the application.

This code will search for the file test.txt in the root of all jars.

If you need to specify a jar that isn't on the classpath, then the other suggestions might be more worthwhile.

Comment: If the jar isn't on the classpath, you can create a custom class loader, and load the resource from that.

Answer (score 3):

If the jar is in the classpath, you can access a file in it using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)`.  If the jar file is not in the classpath, then check out `java.util.jar.JarFile`.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any libraries for working with *.jar files?

Yes, there's [`java.util.zip`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) (jar files are effectively zip files, [more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jar_file)), in the JDK itself (no third-party lib needed).

See also [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) on the Oracle website, which provides examples and such. Here's the code from their first example, unzipping all the files from an archive (not my code, and of course like most examples it has inadequate error checking, etc.):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class UnZip {
   final int BUFFER = 2048;
   public static void main (String argv[]) {
      try {
         BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(argv[0]);
         ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
         ZipEntry entry;
         while((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Extracting: " +entry);
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            // write the files to the disk
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName());
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            while ((count = zis.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
               dest.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            dest.flush();
            dest.close();
         }
         zis.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a separate library. The default zip packages do just fine.

```
private String getFile(File jar, String requestedFile) throws IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //change ouptut stream as required
    ZipInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(jar));
        ZipEntry entry;
        while((entry  = in.getNextEntry())!=null){
            if (entry.getName().equals(requestedFile)){

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (in!=null){
            in.close();
        }
        out.close();

    }
    return new String(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command should work:

`jar xf yyy.jar files/xxx.txt`

Ensure to use correct JDK for the jar for packaging it back using

`jar uf yyy.jar files/xxx.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Open it with any zip utility softwares. .jar is simply a .zip file.

Comment: Then you can use ZIP APIs provided by java to do so. Create ZipInputStream, get ZipEntry and check for name to get your file :)

Answer (score 0):

First check where in `yyy.jar` is your `xxx.txt` located

`jar tf yyy.jar`

Sample output

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
images/pic.gif
files/abc.txt
files/xxx.txt
```

Now that you know the path to xxx.txt,

Extract it by

```
jar xf yyy.jar files/xxx.txt
```