# Image not loading in jar file

Tags: java, jar, imageicon

I am trying to fix this problem. Trying different solutions but nothing works. I am using NetBeans IDE. I created a project with this structure and files:

> E:\java\project\ecadpb\src\ecadpb
>
> The image files are in
>
> E:\java\project\ecadpb\src\

I have specified working folder for my project in Netbeans as `E:\java\project\ecadpb`

I have created my image icons like this

```
new ImageIcon("device21.png");
```

In my source file, it works perfectly while running the project in Netbeans but images are not showing up when I build and run my JAR file separately.  But the image files are inside the JAR.

I have also tried the answers for the same question asked previously.

```
URL imageUrl=getClass().getResource("device21.png");
new ImageIcon(imageUrl);
```

But it doesn't work in my case. I am building a JAR file for the first time.  Can anyone help me with this!!

Comment: This looks allright, what's your error message?

Comment: I dunno wat was the issue.. I was getting the imageUrl as null. I created a ClassLoader using getContextClassLoader and used the getResource to get the URL.. As suggested by @Bitmap . It works now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way of doing this will be to add the image in your classpath or a directory in your classpath say `img` as shown below:

```
E:\java\project\ecadpb\src\main\java\img\device21.png
```

And then load your image from this location like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("img/device21.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resource);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a source folder called Images (ie if you're using eclipse, right-click your project -> new ->sourceFolder). Call it whatever you want, i called my Images. Put some images in it.

Now i had JLabels where i gave them ImageIcons. Look at the following code.

```
    ImageIcon BPawn;
    ImageIcon WPawn;
    JLabel Label = new JLabel[8][8] //2D array of labels that gives each spot a position.
    public void setPieces(){
        //set up pawns in their respective positions.
        BPawn = new ImageIcon("Images/BPawn.png", "BPawn");
        WPawn = new ImageIcon("Images/WPawn.png", "WPawn");
    for(int i=0;i<Label[0].length;i++){
        Label[1][i].setIcon(BPawn);
        Label[6][i].setIcon(WPawn);
    }//end for

    }//end setPieces.
```

There is a lot more in setPieces() method, but this glimpse is how you would reference the images in your source folder when you create an executable jar and want the images to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I think answer could be one these suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7802956/233306)

Comment: No.. My problem is not to take an image from another jar file. The source and the images are in the same jar file. But it is not loading the images.

Comment: @SivaSubramaniam  Did you try the `getResourceAsStream` method?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a similar approach,

a) Specify the package path to the image file name.

b) Make sure that the image file is not ommited by your build scripts and that it is present in your jar file.

Comment: did you try forward or back slashes ... did you check for null object on the imageicon ?

Comment: No.. i'm using the back slashes only.. It is working when i run it in NetBeans.. One more thing i could find is when is use URL imageUrl=getClass().getResource("E:\\java\\project\\ecadpb\\src\\device21.png"), it returns null.. but the image is der in tat location..

Comment: Pls try this 

new ImageIcon(this.class.getResource("/com/r0ast3d/test/test.png"));

Replace this with your current class name... though it shouldnt matter.

Comment: r0ast3d - I tried that - got me "java.lang.NullPointerException"